# Testing JSONProcessingException

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test following code with `JMockito`.

**Code**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StepFunctionClientTest {

    private static final String TEST_STATE_MACHINE_ARN = "testStateMachineArn";
    private static final String TEST_EXECUTION_ARN = "testExecutionArn";
    private ObjectNode additionalData;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Mock AWSStepFunctions mockAWSStepFunctions;
    private StepFunctionClient stepFunctionClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        stepFunctionClient = new StepFunctionClient(mockAWSStepFunctions, TEST_STATE_MACHINE_ARN);
        additionalData = TestData.getObjectNode(TestData.ADDITIONAL_DATA);
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test(expected=InternalServiceException.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        StartExecutionResult result = new StartExecutionResult();
        result.setExecutionArn(TEST_EXECUTION_ARN);

        when(mockAWSStepFunctions.startExecution(any())).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("Error"){});

        stepFunctionClient.startExecution(
                TEST_ORDER_ID,
                TEST_PAYMENT_STATUS,
                null,
                false);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
[junit] Testcase: test(com.project.orderservice.client.StepFunctionClientTest):       Caused an ERROR
[junit] Unexpected exception, expected<com.project.commons.exceptions.InternalServiceException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException>
[junit] java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.project.commons.exceptions.InternalServiceException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException>
[junit]     at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(Unknown Source)
[junit] Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
[junit] Checked exception is invalid for this method!
[junit] Invalid: com.project.orderservice.client.StepFunctionClientTest$1: Error
[junit]     at com.project.orderservice.client.StepFunctionClientTest.test(StepFunctionClientTest.java:157)
```

What i am missing here?

Comment: add the full stacktrace, and the entire test class for better picture

Comment: updated with full code and stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JsonProcessingException](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html) is a checked exception, meaning that if you want to throw it, the method has to have it in its signature. Otherwise you get the error above:

> Checked exception is invalid for this method!

You can throw only the checked exception listed here -> [StartExecutionRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/stepfunctions/AWSStepFunctions.html#startExecution-com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.model.StartExecutionRequest-).

Or a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: thansk for pointing it out. after a little closer look i noticed that `JsonProcessingException` is being thrown by the `ObjectMapper` which is not being mocked in my testcases.

Comment: just add a @Mock annotation then instead of creating the real instance

Comment: what do you mean? `@Mock` annotation where? The `ObjectMapper` is being created internally in `StepFunctionClient`. Can i mock an object which is not being injected from outside?

Comment: If its an instance field then you could use the @InjectMocks on the client